# Regex For Special Character (S with line on top)

Tags: python, regex, ascii

I was trying to write regex in Python to replace all non-ascii with an underscore, but if one of the characters is "`S̄`" (an 'S' with a line on the top), it adds an extra 'S'... Is there a way to account for this character as well? I believe it's a valid utf-8 character, but not ascii

Here's there code:

```
import re
line = "ra*ndom wordS̄"
print(re.sub('[\W]', '_', line))
```

I would expect it to output:

```
ra_ndom_word_
```

But instead I get:

```
ra_ndom_wordS__
```

Comment: `"S̄" ` is actually _two_ characters: `LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S` (which is ASCII) followed by `COMBINING MACRON`, which is not.

Comment: I can't repro; I get `S_` at the end, not `__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason Python works this way is that you are actually looking at two distinct characters; there's an `S` and then it's followed by a combining macron [U+0304](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/304/index.htm)

In the general case, if you want to replace a sequence of combining characters and the base character with an underscore, try e.g.

```
import unicodedata

def cleanup(line):
    cleaned = []
    strip = False
    for char in line:
        if unicodedata.combining(char):
            strip = True
            continue
        if strip:
            cleaned.pop()
            strip = False
        if unicodedata.category(char) not in ("Ll", "Lu"):
            char = "_"
        cleaned.append(char)
    return ''.join(cleaned)
```

By the by, `\W` does not need square brackets around it; it's already a regex character class.

Python's `re` module lacks support for important Unicode properties, though if you really want to use specifically a regex for this, the third-party `regex` library has proper support for Unicode categories.

`"Ll"` is lowercase alphabetics and `"Lu"` are uppercase. There are other Unicode L categories so maybe tweak this to suit your requirements (`unicodedata.category(char).startswith("L")` maybe?); see also https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thanks; fixed. Also, sorry OP for the back and forth while I debugged this; my first attempt was slightly off.

Comment: Ah, so if I wanted to also keep capitalized letters as well, `re`, or even this code snippet, wouldn't be enough, right?

Comment: I added uppercase just to show how it's done. I think ideally you'd probably be well served by a good regex if you can articulate one, but like I wrote in the answer, Python's `re` module doesn't have any mechanism to access the Unicode categories that you'd probably want to use. I suppose you could hard-code a selection of characters instead of using the actual Unicode database but that's obviously hard to maintain for any longer period of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following script to get the desired output:

```
import re

line="ra*ndom wordS̄"
print(re.sub('[^[-~]+]*','_',line))
```

Output

```
ra_ndom_word_
```

In this approach, it works with other non-ascii characters as well :

```
import re

line="ra*ndom ¡¢£Ä wordS̄.  another non-ascii: Ä and Ï"
print(re.sub('[^[-~]+]*','_',line))
```

output:

```
ra_ndom_word_another_non_ascii_and_
```